# Non-linear fitting with uncertainty in dependent and independent variable

Tags: model-selection, nonlinear-regression, error, fitting, uncertainty

This is related with [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/113987/lm-weights-and-the-standard-error).

What is the best strategy/package in R/python/Mathematica to fit a non-linear model to data with uncertainty measures in both variables?

Elaborating:

For every data point, I have several measures of two variables, $X$ and $Z$. The different measures can be treated as independent replicates. I compute $\tilde{X}$ and $\tilde{Z}$ for every data point and then calculate a third variable $Y = \tilde{Z}-\tilde{X}$. I have a non-linear model that computes $Y$ ~ f($\tilde{X}$,$p_{1}$,...). (I'm testing also different models, that's why I did not specify the number of parameters, as they change).

Now, how to do this fitting but taking into account the uncertainty in both $\tilde{X}$ and $Y$? As stated in the linked question, I'm not interested only in weighting the points, I want to propagate the uncertainty to parameter estimation.

More doubts:
For different data points I have different number of measures for $X$ and $Z$. What should be used as the uncertainty of $X$ and $Z$? The standard deviation or the standard error of the mean?

The error on $Y$ should be $Y_{err}=\sqrt{X_{err}^{2}+Z_{err}^{2}}$ right?

What is an acceptable measure of goodness of fit? Adjusted R squared?

How to compare different models? I feel like I could use BIC, but for that I need to compute the log likelihood...